# Enabling/Disabling Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport

Tags: windows-8, wifi

I disabled my `Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport` network adapter from `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`.

Just right clicked on the miniport nic and clicked disable, and its gone. Now how could I enable it?
After disabling the nic, `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` is not working any more. The response is,

`The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.`

It was working flawlessly, before I disabled the adapter,
Anyway, for reference here is the output of 
`netsh wlan show drivers,`

`Interface name: Wi-Fi`

```
Driver                    : Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
Vendor                    : Qualcomm Atheros Communications Inc.
Provider                  : Microsoft
Date                      : 7/3/2012
Version                   : 3.0.0.130
INF file                  : C:\Windows\INF\netathrx.inf
Files                     : 2 total
                            C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\athrx.sys
                            C:\Windows\system32\drivers\vwifibus.sys
Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
Radio types supported     : 802.11b 802.11g 802.11n
FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
Hosted network supported  : Yes
Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                            Open            None
                            Open            WEP-40bit
                            Open            WEP-104bit
                            Open            WEP
                            WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                            WPA-Personal    TKIP
                            WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                            WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                            Vendor defined  TKIP
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                            WPA-Personal    CCMP
                            WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                            Vendor defined  CCMP
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
Authentication and cipher supported in ad-hoc mode:
                            Open            None
                            Open            WEP-40bit
                            Open            WEP-104bit
                            Open            WEP
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
```

`netsh wlan show hostednetwork,`

### Hosted network settings

```
Mode                   : Allowed
SSID name              : "aczire"
Max number of clients  : 100
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP
```

### Hosted network status

```
Status                 : Not available
```

After executing,

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow`

`The hosted network mode has been set to allow.`

But again in,

`netsh wlan show hostednetwork`

### Hosted network settings

```
Mode                   : Allowed
SSID name              : "aczire"
Max number of clients  : 100
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP
```

### Hosted network status

```
Status                 : Not available
```

`netsh wlan show settings`

### Wireless LAN settings

```
Show blocked networks in visible network list: No
Only use GP profiles on GP-configured networks: No
Hosted network mode allowed in WLAN service: Yes
Allow shared user credentials for network authentication: Yes
Block period: Not Configured.
Auto configuration logic is enabled on interface "Wi-Fi"
```

Any idea how to re-enable the Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport adapter (in Windows 8 Pro RTM)? 
I'm at my wits end, Please help :(

Comment: Just follow instructions in this link <http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Set-Up-a-Wireless-Hotspot-Windows-7/step1/Step-1-Enabling-the-Microsoft-Virtual-WiFi-Minipo/>

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You go to your "device manager", find your "network adapters", then should find the virtual wifi adapter, then right click it and enable it. After that, you start your cmd with admin privileges, then try:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me. The Virtual Adapter is enabled but it's not visible in control panel --> network adapters. Trying to uninstall it / dis-re-enable it / dis-re-allow hostednetwork does not work for me.

Comment: @A.Danischewski Still missing for me.

Answer (score 16):

From accepted answer:

> You go to your "device manager", find your "network adapters", then should find the virtual wifi adapter, then right click it and enable it

Maybe your device is hidden - first you should unhide it from the device manger, then re-enable the adapter from the device manger tools.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact problem and I couldn't find the hosted network adapter in network connections or device manager. So what I did was to disable and enable the wifi adapter after this the hosted network adapter should be listed in the device manager, then you just enable the adapter from there.

Comment: Tip: if the adapter doesn't seem to be disabled in Device Manager, try closing and re-opening Device Manager. Just pressing F5 won't refresh the list.

Comment: The answer and the first comment here combines a perfect answer to this problem. It's quite a bit strange behavior in Windows 10 because as far as I remember in Windows 7, the adapter icon of the virtual wifi adapter won't  be disappeared after being disabled.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue after I disabled the adapter in the Network setting. But when I go to the System->Device Manager and find it from the "Network adapters" and re-enable it. Then everything works again.

Comment: Thanks, it helped for my scenario!

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to uninstall and reinstall the wireless adapter driver to be able to execute the command

Comment: Tried this after everything else, still doesn't work. It used to, just quit randomly, around the same time that my VMWare player network drivers quit as well..I have to use a USB wifi stick to set up a hosted network now.

Answer (score 2):

In the device manager you can select
View > Show hidden devices

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport` should start and bind automatically to the underlying function driver. Try disabling and reenabling the `AR9285` driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this hotfix:
hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%207/Windows%20Server2008%20R2%20SP1/sp2/Fix362872/7600/free/427221_intl_i386_zip.exe

Answer (score 0):

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Set-Up-a-Wireless-Hotspot-Windows-7/step1/Step-1-Enabling-the-Microsoft-Virtual-WiFi-Minipor/

and then execute in command prompt (ADMIN)

> netsh wlan start hostednetwork