# Error Enable / disabled Hotspot Virtual Wifi in Windows 10

Tags: wifi, windows-10, host

I have a problem when trying to create my connection hostpot vitual wifi on a Dell laptop with Win 10.

Even with some instabilities the ad hoc connection worked by running a script that I ran from a **.bat** file in the administrator option:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=WifiTeste key=senhateste123
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

But after changing some of ethernet sharing settings on network connections it began to appear the following error:

```
The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
```

Redid the command several times, changed the network name and password, and even tried using the Virtual Router Manager program and after extensive research I did not get even succeeded in reconfiguring the wifi hotspot on windows 10.

Most solutions are functional only for Win 7 or 8 and the process of creating a new ad hoc network connection is not available in win 10, or at least I have not found how to do.

An important point is that when the script worked was created a network connection **"Wireless Connection LAN * 2"**, to run the ipconfig / all in cmd it will appear disconnected with state media and in **"Control Panel-> Network and Internet-> Network Connections "** it is no longer visible.

Solution already evaluated:
[Enabling/Disabling Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656694/enabling-disabling-microsoft-virtual-wifi-miniport)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Right click **cmd** (Run as administrator)
2. Type `netsh wlan show drivers` (this is important).
   Now you can see your wifi driver details. Note these lines:

> - FIPS 140-2 MODE SUPPORTED : **No**
> - 802.11W Management Frame Protection supported : **No**
> - Hosted network supported : **Yes**

If the first two lines are not supported you cannot use adhoc or Hotspot Pro. They should be: **Yes**.
Now open **Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings -> right click your wireless connection -> click Properties -> select Sharing Tab.**  Check both of the items **Allow other network users to connect...** and select your "Wireless Connection" and check **Allow other network users to control...**

3. Now restart your computer. Follow the steps 1 & 2
   Now you can see the first two lines should be "Yes"
4. If it is **"Yes"** type next command.
5. `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=WifiTeste key=senhateste123`
6. `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`

Now you can see "hostednetwork started" message will appear.

*Note: If you want to connect your mobile device, put your ssid and password and wait for one minute.  Otherwise it will say "internet not available".*

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple here. If the above solutions doesn't work, then do the following:

a) Right click on MyPC/MyComputer

b) Click on 'View' menu and select 'Show Hidden Devices'

c) Check for disabled virtual adapter under 'Network adapters' and enable it.

Comment: Sorry I missed some steps. after step a. and before step b. please follow below steps: a1) select 'Manage' a2) click on 'Device Manager'

Answer (score 0):

I have done all these steps and it started working for Windows 10.

1) Download Microsoft Virtual wifi adapter ( Link : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52425 ). Search in google if link expires.

2) Press Windows Key + X > Device Manager > Network Adapters > Select Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2 ( or something similar with the term wifi on it ) > Uninstall device ( feel free to do this. It reinstalls automatically later ) > Reboot > It should work.

P.S. : Please note mine is working even when Hosted network supported is set at No.